# Dired. Is it possible to change color of file name when file was changed?

Tags: dired, faces

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

I use Dired+ as file manager. All files names color are yellow.

If some file was changed not later than one hour ago then :

1. this file name change it color, e.g blue
2. after one hour it return to it old color - yellow

It's possible in Emacs?

Comment: See standard libraries `filenotify.el` and `auto-revert.el`, including function `file-notify-add-watch`.